# Tcl how I could display a name in this script?

Tags: linux, bash, tcl

Im use tcl but  i dont know how display a string alphanumeric with this script code

```html
  
#!/usr/bin/wish
 
wm title . "Feet to Meters"
grid [ttk::frame .c -padding "3 3 12 12"] -column 0 -row 0 -sticky nwes
grid columnconfigure . 0 -weight 1; grid rowconfigure . 0 -weight 1

grid [ttk::entry .c.feet -width 7 -textvariable feet] -column 2 -row 1 -sticky we
grid [ttk::label .c.meters -textvariable meters] -column 2 -row 2 -sticky we
grid [ttk::label .c.meter2s -textvariable meters2] -column 6 -row 2 -sticky we
grid [ttk::button .c.calc -text "Calculate" -command calculate] -column 3 -row 3 -sticky w
grid [ttk::entry .c.feet2 -width 7 -textvariable feet2] -column 7 -row 1 -sticky we

grid [ttk::label .c.flbl -text "feet"] -column 3 -row 1 -sticky w
grid [ttk::label .c.flbl2 -text "feet2"] -column 6 -row 1 -sticky w
grid [ttk::label .c.islbl -text "is equivalent to"] -column 1 -row 2 -sticky e
grid [ttk::label .c.mlbl -text "meters"] -column 3 -row 2 -sticky w
grid [ttk::label .c.mlbl2 -text "meters2"] -column 4 -row 2 -sticky w

foreach w [winfo children .c] {grid configure $w -padx 5 -pady 5}
focus .c.feet
bind . <Return> {calculate}

proc calculate {} {  
   if {[catch {
       set ::meters [expr {round($::feet*0.3048*10000.0)/10000.0}]
       set ::meters2 [ feet2 ]
   }]!=0} {
       set ::meters ""
   }
}
```

in this part the script fails

```
in this part the script fails

   set ::meters2 [ feet2 ]
```

I want to display the feet2 value when write a text and press calculate

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
proc calculate {} {
   if {[catch {
       set ::meters [expr {round($::feet*0.3048*10000.0)/10000.0}]
       set ::meters2 $::feet2
   }]!=0} {
       set ::meters error
       set ::meters2 error2
   }
}
```

Comment: yes very thankyou this help me so much ; Im new in tcl .